# Angular2 Nested formGroups - formArrays and template Binding

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

Here is the problem:

I have a complex form with nested formgroups, here is a "simplified" structure of what it looks like :

```
-> MyForm (formGroup)
    -> Whatever01 (formControl - input)
    -> Whatever02 (formControl - input)
    -> WhateverGroup01 (formGroup)
        -> Whatever03 (formControl - input)
        -> Whatever04 (formControl - input)
    -> WhateverArray01 (formArray)
        -> WhateverGroup02 (formGroup)
            -> Whatever05 (formControl - input)
            -> WhateverGroup03 (formGroup)
                -> Whatever06 (formControl - input)
        -> WhateverGroup04 (formGroup)
            -> Whatever07 (formControl - input)
    -> ...
```

Angular side, it should look somehow like this (not correct/complete, but just to give an idea) :

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    whatever01: ['',Validators.compose([...])],
    whatever02: ['',Validators.compose([...])],
    whateverGroup01: this._formBuilder.group({
        whatever03: ['',Validators.compose([...])],
        whatever04: ['',Validators.compose([...])]
    }),
    whateverArray01: this._formBuilder.array([
        this._formBuilder.group({
            whatever05: ['',Validators.compose([...])],
            whateverGroup03: this._formBuilder.group({
                whatever06: ['',Validators.compose([...])]
            })
        }),
        this._formBuilder.group({
            whatever07: ['',Validators.compose([...])],
        })
    ])
    ...
});
```

Things go pretty fine from root myForm item to fetching the formArray, but then come the troubles....

So, I just can't access "whatever05" (and 06 but 05 does NOT work... so...) formControl to bind it to the template ! Here is what the template actually looks like (intentionnaly skipped the part before the array), the interesting part is the [????]="????", this is the problem actually.

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" ...>
    <!-- ...skipped... -->
    <div formArrayName="whateverArray01" *ngFor="let item of myForm.controls.whateverGroup01.controls.whateverArray01.controls;let idx = index;" [formGroupName]="idx">
        <div [????]="????">
            <input formControlName="whatever05" ... />
            <div [????]="????">
                <input formControlName="whatever06" ... />
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</form>
```

The formGroups located in the formArray have all the same structure.

Basically, the problem is that I canNOT access the formControls within the formGroups...

I tried several solutions, I used [formGroupName] , formGroupName (without brackets), [formGroup], formControlName, ... But cannot figure out what I have to use to be able to bind the corresponding formGroup/formControl with the data !

I come to this kind of errors by now :

```
formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in. 
// This when using [formGroup]="item.whateverGroup02"

Cannot find control with name: 'whatever05'
// When using [formGroup]="item.controls.whateverGroup02"

Cannot find control with path: 'whateverArray01 -> 0 ->'
// This when using [formGroupName]="whateverGroup02"
```

Thanks for reading / help

Here is a plunker with some code :

http://plnkr.co/edit/wf7fcHMkhIwzmLWLnCF8?p=preview

Comment: formArrayName needs to be in a wrapping element for formGroupName.

Comment: Also this beast right here `myForm.controls.whateverGroup01.controls.whateverArray01.controls` can be condensed to `myForm.get('whateverGroup.whateverArray').`

Comment: Also I think FormArray needs to have identical nested FormGroups.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for comments, My formGroups inside formArray all have the same structure. This will not be a problem. I dont understand what you mean in your first comment...

Comment: It's not the same in your example above. I mean that you are declaring formArrayName and formGroupName in the same element. Move formArrayName to a higher up element.

Comment: But my formArray is part of a formGroup in my case!

Comment: anyway, it will always be part of a formgroup since the form itself is a formgroup. It should not cause problems...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142206/discussion-between-julo0ss-and-unitario).

Answer (score 2):

The build of your form seems correct to me. You have some trouble in your template, the iteration of your `FormArray` is incorrect, your `FormArray` is not inside the `FormGroup` `WhateverGroup01`, so the iteration should look like this:

```html
*ngFor="let ctrl of myForm.controls.whateverArray01.controls;
```

As to the template part of your `FormArray`, it should look like this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let ctrl of myForm.controls.whateverArray01.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
   <input formControlName="whatever05" />
   <div formGroupName="whateverGroup03">
      <input formControlName="whatever06" />
   </div>
</div>
```

That should solve the issue :)

Here's a

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ijmx86alGKQxJo4hrmzZhttp://)

Comment: Well, this is a good point, but this does not exactly solve my issue. I don't have this nested issue. But you're right about it, its a mistake from my copy... I updated the question with a "non-working" plunker. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all your view has wrong binding:

```
[formGroupName]="whateverGroup02"
```

There is no `whateverGroup02` property in your component. We should pass string as follows:

```
formGroupName="whateverGroup02"
```

Then if you build group like:

```
this.fb.group({
  x: 1,
  y: {
    z: 2
  }
})
```

you will get

```
FormGroup
  -> FormControl with name `x` and value `1`   
  -> FormControl with name `y` and value `{ z: 2 }`
```

It means if you want to manipulate nested formGroups you have to create their. 
i.e.

```
let fGroups = data.map(rs => this.buildFormGroup(rs));
...
buildFormGroup(obj) {
  let formGroup: { [id: string]: AbstractControl; } = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    formGroup[key] = typeof obj[key] === 'object' ?
      this.buildFormGroup(obj[key]) : 
      new FormControl(obj[key]);
  });
  return this._formBuilder.group(formGroup);
}
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/3k23R3z2KHlAXW5OLKRA?p=preview)**

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your reply! Checked the example, this actually solves the problem for the formGroup, but what if there were also nested formArrays? Should I add a "buildFormArray" function or something? Thx