# how to set value to a FormGroup contains FormArray in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

If I have some data, the data struct like this:

```
interface IProject {
   name: string;
   tasks: ITask[];
}
interface ITask {
   name: string;
   employee: IEmployee[];
}
interface IEmployee {
   name: string;
}
```

And now I have some project data like this:

```
project = {
    name: 'first project',
    tasks: [
        {
            name: 'task1',
            employee: [{name: 'employee1'}, {name: 'employee2'}],
        },
        {
            name: 'task2',
            employee: [{name: 'employee2'}, {name: 'employee3'}],
        },
    ],
}
```

Maybe this way is useful:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        name: [this.project.name],
        tasks: this.fb.array([]),
    });
    this.setTasks();
}

setTasks() {
    const taskControl = <FormArray>this.form.controls.tasks;
    this.project.tasks.forEach(t => {
        const taskForm = this.fb.group({
            name: [t.name],
            exployee: this.fb.array([]),
        });
        const employeeControl = <FormArray>taskForm.controls.exployee;
        t.exployee.forEach(e => {
            employeeControl.push(this.fb.group({name: [e.name]}));
        }
        taskControl.push(employeeControl);
    }
}
```

Is there any elegant way to build a FormGroup with FormArray and set these data to the form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37212948/typescript-angular2-cast-json-to-interface-with-observable-jsonp

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/deep-nested-reactive-form?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @Chellappan Thank you.This is very helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

You want to serialize/deserialize interfaces to JSON. [Serializr](https://medium.com/@mweststrate/introducing-serializr-serializing-and-deserializing-object-graphs-with-ease-8833c3fcea02) can do it.

```
class User {
    @serializable name;
}

class Message {
    @serializable
    author;

    @serializable
    message;
}

deserialize(Message, {
    "message": "test",
    "author": 123
});
```

Here's a more [throughout tutorial](https://medium.com/@mweststrate/introducing-serializr-serializing-and-deserializing-object-graphs-with-ease-8833c3fcea02).

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I didn't describe my doubts clearly. I want to find a beautiful way to set this json data to a reactive form.

Comment: I find a useful question that I didn't found before asking. That my fault. [Angular2 Nested formGroups - formArrays and template Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43526092/angular2-nested-formgroups-formarrays-and-template-binding)